# IOS how to reload a webview

Tags: ios5

Some help please,

I am putting a web app together and I am stuck on a few things.
I have tabviewcontrollers which load different uiwebviews.

Each time I navigate on the app and re-click the tab it remains where I was on that page is there a way to re-load it so it always goes from the orginal ur (not just a refresh)?

Any advice on the best way to handle this would be appreciated.

Thank you

Steve

Answer (score 0):

Load the request in your view controller's `viewWillAppear:` method.

Comment: [webView reload];   It doesn't reload back to the orginal "url" it stays on the page the user browsed to before clicking off.  Is there a way for it to open the one url as stipulated in the orginal uiwebview

Comment: I didn't say reload.  Obviously reload is just going to reload what you've currently got.  I said load the request.  If you've got content in there already, you're already loading the request using a method like `loadRequest:` - just put this call in the `viewWillAppear:` method.

Comment: Sorry some confusion.  I make the request in the viewWillAppear: and the viewDidAppear.  When I click off the tab bar button to another and return it works however it won't refresh if i'm already on the view and click the already clicked button if that makes sense?

Comment: So the problem is not reloading the web view at all?  It's that tapping on a tab when that tab is active doesn't reload the tab?  That's how tabs are supposed to work.  They aren't buttons to perform actions, they are for switching between different sections of your application.  If you're already in a section, tapping the tab for that section isn't supposed to do anything because you're already in it.

Comment: Right I see and makes complete sense could you recommend a way of getting round this or alternatively a different 'tab bar' to use?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to refresh, use

```
[webView reload]
```

or for if you want t reload with a specific url

```
NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://urltoreload.html"];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL]];
```